# setrlimit(RLIMIT_CORE) failed for pid 17930: Operation not permitted

Tags: android, google-drive-api

[image]

Am trying to make android google drive api application and i got this error ..

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide a [minimal working example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and your code as text, otherwise people won't be able to assist you.